# Unity 3D single build for various projects

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build

I need to develop a single Unity3D standalone build for separate project modules.

Consider, I have various projects related to 'Physics' for the 12th grade, which contains separate models, images and their respective functionality. For example, Project1: 'Optics', Project2: 'Electrostatics', Project3: 'Dual Nature of matter' and so on. All of these projects are independent of each other in terms of functionality and are complete on their own. Now, I create a 'Unity build'(say, for android initially) that contains a menu layout along with hyperlinks to download separate projects aforementioned from a server. The requirement is to allow the user to download a project(Say, project1: 'Optics') jar/build out of many projects available as an extension/addition to the previous 'Unity build'(even if the size of the build already installed might increase on device). As soon as the project is downloaded, the user should be able to run the project module over the 'Unity Build' instead of running a separate application. Similarly, when the user is done with the downloaded project module(Project1: 'Optics'), another project module(say,Project2 : 'Electrostatics') can be downloaded from the menu of the build which will run over the same 'Unity Build'. The 'Unity build' application serves as an interface which can add a separate layer of encryption so that the projects cannot be downloaded over and run separately by any unrestricted user. Somewhat similar to a media player which can play various kinds of video files. However, in this scenario, I need to run various project modules.

I am looking to create builds for different platforms - Android, Windows, iOS and Web browser (if possible) with similar functionality.
Any kind of help will be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a an "example" that comes with Unity as an install option and I believe it does exactly what you want, it has a menu where you can select different demos, where each demo is a project in itself. You should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mostly about organisation.

- Sounds like your 'Unity build' is a kind of downloader with menue. May be this could be a website. Is the server a webserver?
- The server has to have all projects for all possible plattforms, like a matrix.
- If somebody starts to download a project, you have to choose the right build for his plattform.
- To estimate the plattform, you could send a parameter with the link.

All of these points have many solutions depending on your requirements.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

## What you need are Asset Bundles.

### What are they?

Compressed packages that serve as game extensions that can be downloaded and imported to a unity build at any time. With AssetBundles you can package scenes and load them into unity and load them.

### How to create AssetBundles?

Basically you can select any Asset from your project and in the inspector you assign that Asset to a new AssetBundle in the inspector (at the bottom it says Create AssetBundle). A detailed section can be read here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildingAssetBundles.html

In your case you should create many Asset Bundles with one scene in each.

### How to download and load unity scene files from AssetBundles?

It could be a bit tricky but it has already been accomplished here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/dynamically-load-scene-from-assetbundle.379316/

### Common pitfall

Remember that AssetBundles aren't cross platform compatible. In other words, the Asset Bundle created is restricted only to the platform it is built for so you need to recreate your AssetBundles for each platform

Hope this helped!